# Image from Gallery is not being set to imageview

Tags: android

I have a listview and a button. When the button is clicked, it leads to the gallery where the user can choose a picture. When I test my app and go to the gallery, when I select a picture, the imageview isn't updated with that picture. Here is my imageview and button:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/change_background" />
```

And my coding:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class Personalize extends Activity{
Button button;
ImageView image;
Button btnChangeImage;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String  selectedImagePath;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.personalize);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2Icon);

    btnChangeImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);
    btnChangeImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
        }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
            {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
                    {
                        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                        try {
                            FileInputStream fileis=new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
                            BufferedInputStream bufferedstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileis);
                            byte[] bMapArray= new byte[bufferedstream.available()];
                            bufferedstream.read(bMapArray);
                            Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
                            //Here you can set this /Bitmap image to the button background image

                            if (fileis != null) 
                            {
                                fileis.close();
                            }
                            if (bufferedstream != null) 
                            {
                                bufferedstream.close();
                            }
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                 
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {                   
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }               
                    }
                }
            }


        public String getPath(Uri uri) {
                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }

    });


    } 
}
```

ADDED:
Full code for xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/personalizetextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/customize" 
    android:textSize="30dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"/>

  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/personalizetextviewChangeBackground"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/customizebackground"
    android:gravity="center" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/pattern1"
    />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/change_background" />

  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/personalizetextviewChangeIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/change_icon"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2Icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/pattern2" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeImageForIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/change_icon" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Full code for Personalize.java:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Personalize extends Activity{
Button button;
ImageView image;
ImageView image2;
Button btnChangeImage;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String  selectedImagePath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.personalize);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    btnChangeImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);
    btnChangeImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
        }

    });


    } 

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
        {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            try {
                FileInputStream fileis=new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
                BufferedInputStream bufferedstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileis);
                byte[] bMapArray= new byte[bufferedstream.available()];
                bufferedstream.read(bMapArray);
                Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
                //Here you can set this /Bitmap image to the button background image

                if (fileis != null) 
                {
                    fileis.close();
                }
                if (bufferedstream != null) 
                {
                    bufferedstream.close();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                 
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {                   
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I will add the other coding to update the icon since I can just carry over the same coding and modify the names of resources as needed

Comment: Is there any logcat output from the `e.printStackTrace()` lines?

Comment: Suprizingly, it just suddenly started to work. I have a new issue of the chosen picture taking up too much room though in the imageview.

Comment: Nevermind I figured out how to fix this. Thanks for all your help! I guess a combination of everyone's comments worked out somehow. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `onActivityResult()` and `getPath()` are both inside your `OnClickListener`. Try moving them out to be methods of `Personalize` instead. You'll also need to add `@Override` to `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: I changed that but it still doesn't update the view when I select an image from the gallery. I'll post my full code this time too, please check the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the line where you set the ImageView with the selected "picture".

After this line:

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
```

Add this:

```
image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Comment: Ok thanks but that still doesn't update the image when I run my app

Comment: Nevermind I figured out how to fix this. Thanks for all your help! I guess a combination of everyone's comments worked out somehow because it suddenly started to work! :D

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the image like this:

```
     Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
     selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
     Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
     image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Instead of do:

```
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        try {
            FileInputStream fileis=new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileis);
            byte[] bMapArray= new byte[bufferedstream.available()];
            bufferedstream.read(bMapArray);
            Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
            //Here you can set this /Bitmap image to the button background image

            if (fileis != null) 
            {
                fileis.close();
            }
            if (bufferedstream != null) 
            {
                bufferedstream.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {                   
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Let me know if this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: So if you mean to replace it, when I do that I get a bunch of errors on the next lines saying things aren't defined (which makes sense because the are defined in the chunk of code taken out), so when I delete those it tells me to give a finally statement. What would that be?

Comment: Nevermind I figured out how to fix this. Thanks for all your help! I guess a combination of everyone's comments worked out somehow because it suddenly started to work! :D